# GMT to EST time zone in apex

Tags: apex, datetime, timezone

How can I convert GMT to EST using `Apex`? I have EST as my timezone settings but still all the `DateTime` fields are in GMT timezone.

Comment: When displayed in Visualforce, DateTime fields will display in the context of the user's time zone. Salesforce stores all DateTime data in GMT regardless of where the user is at, applying the offset at the time of the DML. Is there a reason you need to work with the data in one particular time zone? I'll add that if you do, it can be problematic when daylight savings time comes and goes twice a year.

Comment: Agreed that you should avoid converting time zones if there is any way at all to avoid it. Can you describe your use case?

Answer (score 5):

In apex use dateTime `format(dateFormatString, timezone)` method

```
DateTime dtGmt = system.now();

system.debug('========THIS will return Current GMT time====='+dtGmt);
system.debug('=======This will return Current New_York time====='+dtGmt.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss','America/New_York'));
```